# How many points for all four safeties?

Tags: mille-bornes

How many points are awarded for all four safeties played by the same team or player in Mille Bornes - 300 or 700?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're playing an edition by Parker Brothers (where the game is played over multiple hands and the first to 5,000 points wins), you get a hundred-point bonus for each safety played, and another 300 bonus if you play all four safeties, according to https://gamerules.com/rules/mille-bornes-card-game/ and https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/MilleBornes.pdf :

> SCORING
>
> Score as many points as miles traveled ... X
>
> Bonus for 1000 mile trip ............... 400
>
> Bonus for safety card .................. 100
>
> All 4 Safety Cards played by 1 team .... 300
>
> Each Coup Fourré ....................... 300
>
> Delayed Action ..........................300
>
> Safe Trip .............................. 300
>
> Shut Out ............................... 500

The 300 points bonus for al four is explicitly "in addition" to the 100 points for each one:

(Again from https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/MilleBornes.pdf ):

> All four Safety Cards played by the same team (add this bonus to the 100 points scored for each safety card): 300

And also confirmed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mille_Bornes)

> All 4 safeties: 300 bonus in addition to the standard 100 points for each of the safeties individually plus any coup-fourré bonuses.

ADDENDUM:

If you're playing the [Dujardin](https://images-cdn.asmodee.us/filer_public/31/fc/31fc285a-2300-4d90-a55f-4c0415453e14/mib01_rules.pdf) edition, the games is just one hand (ending at 1,000 miles), and there's no bonus for playing all four safeties.

Answer (score 0):

I question the rule set LScottJohnson pointed to, as in that rule set, it says the object of the game is to travel 5000 miles.  Every variant I've played, the game goes to the eponymous 1000.

In my physically printed rules (Copyright 2014 Dujardin):

- 100 points when you play a safety card.
- 200 points if you play it as a Coup Fourre'.  i.e. you play it immediately when someone plays a hazard on you, and "counter" the hazard.
- There are no special bonuses for playing all 4 safety cards.

Note, if you are playing to 1000, and play all 4 safety cards as Coup Fourre', you'll have 800 points, and will win very shortly if you haven't already, as no one can now block you.

Comment: I think you've misread. Both of the the rules set I pointed to say "1,000 miles" in each hand, with the game being won at 5,000 points. If there's a rules set that says the game is won at 1,000 points, please cite it.

Comment: Ah, found the Dujardin rules (https://images-cdn.asmodee.us/filer_public/31/fc/31fc285a-2300-4d90-a55f-4c0415453e14/mib01_rules.pdf) -- yes that is certainly a different set of rules than the OP is using: there's no bonus there for all four safeties at all. AFAIK, all versions published by Parker Brothers have used the multiple-hand scoring method (to 5,000 points) rather than the single-hand game described in the Dujardin version.